# How to get the window Id of a window in the White library

Tags: c#, white-framework

I am trying to get a window id from the White framework. I would like to store the id in a database then later attach to the window again. Here is the code I am working with:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(_path);
_application = White.Core.Application.AttachOrLaunch(psi);
_window = _application.GetWindow(SearchCriteria.ByText(_title), InitializeOption.NoCache);
var id = _window.Id;
```

As you can see var id = _window.Id; returns a null value. Do you know of any way to refer to a window?

Comment: `_window` is null or `_window.Id` is null? The `Id` is simply the underlying `AutomationElement.Current.AutomationId` property. If the application author did not assign one then it may very well be null (although if unassigned it is usually the empty string).

Comment: @mike - _window is not null. _window.Id is null. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the window title to get the window every time, there is no performance difference afaik using the title vs the automation id for finding windows.